# Equivalent of C# async main in F#

Tags: f#, async-await, f#-async

I was wondering what would be the equivalent of the C# async `main` in F#. More to the point, is there a special way of consuming/using async methods from `main` in an F# program or is it just a matter of waiting for completion?

To be more concrete, say we are using the .NET Core Generic Host.

In a C# program, `main` might look like this:

```
class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
         await new HostBuilder().Build().RunAsync();
    }
}
```

In an F# program, my instinct would be to do something like this:

```
[<EntryPoint>]
let main args =
    HostBuilder().Build.RunAsync().Wait()
```

...or...

```
[<EntryPoint>]
let main args =
    HostBuilder().Build.RunAsync() |> Async.AwaitTask |> Async.RunSynchronously
```

...or...

```
[<EntryPoint>]
let main args = 
    async {
        return HostBuilder().Build.RunAsync() |> Async.AwaitTask
    } |> Async.RunSynchronously
```

...or just avoid async...but that's no fun...

```
[<EntryPoint>]
let main args =
    HostBuilder().Build.Run()
```

There are a few more formulations I could show but I think these make the point.

I imagine that part of the answer lies in answering these other questions

1. "what does it mean to run an async main method" and
2. "what's the point of making main async?"

Going by examples, async `main` seems mostly to be about making it possible for other places to call `main` in an async way (in those cases where `main` is not really "main", ie. unit testing, etc).

In the case of F#, I imagine there are at least 2 things preventing one from just returning an Async computation from `main`:

1. The EntryPointAttribute that enforces an int return type for status codes...right?
2. The compiler probably is not prepared to handle the async computation as the exit value of the program...right?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

AFAIK there's no async main equivalent in F#.

If you look at C# implementation behind the scenes it looks like this:

```
private static void <Main>(string[] args)
{
   Program.Main(args).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}
```

Program.Main is the async main.

Personally I find this pattern slightly scary depending on what SynchronizationContext is used.

To emulate async main I would:

```
let theAsyncTask : Async<int> = ...

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
  async {
    do! Async.SwitchToThreadPool ()
    return! theAsyncTask
  } |> Async.RunSynchronously
```

`theAsyncTask` is the actual work to be done, the embedded `async` switches to the thread pool so that the `main` thread can safely block and await the result.

Comment: Why is `Async.SwitchToThreadPool` needed? Couldn't you just do `mainAsync argv |> Async.RunSynchronously`?